# Where should we post feature requests for Stack Exchange betas?

Tags: support, area-51, stackexchange-2.0

This might sound like a silly question, but with 11 Area 51 sites in beta, I can't imagine that team members spend copious amounts of time monitoring all of them, especially their metas.

So, if we have a request that we think is specific to a single beta (i.e. doesn't seem relevant to S[OFU]), is it better to bring it up (a) here, (b) on the beta's meta, or (c) somewhere else?

Comment: "beta's meta" --> "beta meta" --> rhyme :)

Comment: @Maxim Z.: beta meta -> betta meta -> better meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely (b). Right now, I *do* spend "copious amounts of time monitoring" the Stack Exchange metas. But I will not be able continue to scale beyond many more sites.

That's why I am in the process of [appointing and organizing provisional moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site/58056#58056) until the Stack Exchange sites can hold their own elections. Besides the normal Moderator activities, **part of their function will be to act as ambassadors** — liaisons between Stack Overflow and the individual sites — to identify and bring these issues to us.

If there's an idea/feature-request for a *specific* community, it's up to that community to vet the idea in the same way we do here (i.e. in their own meta). If the idea passes muster, it would be passed on to us for consideration, through their own governance.

Of course, if the idea involves the core engine or the Network, the idea should be raised in http://meta.stackoverflow.com. Pretty cool, huh?

Answer (score 4):

Clearly (b) -- is there any reason to expect otherwise?

Comment: Yes, there is - because team members spend about 50x more time here than they do there, and the only 2 `feature-request` posts on one beta that received an official response were back on July 10-11.  I'm not complaining, there's nothing terribly urgent, but nevertheless that's why I asked - it's not at all clear to me whether or not the SE team actually checks those metas.

Comment: @aarobot anything site-specific I see here I am deleting the instant I see it, without hesitation. If it happens enough, I will permanently ban accounts network-wide. That clear enough? :)

Comment: Crystal clear.  I also just found [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55513/request-for-official-clarification-on-proper-location-of-meta-questions-for-se-2) question.  Perhaps you should update or answer it in some form.  I will certainly use the site-specific meta for these, but please understand that the distinction may not be as obvious to us users as it is to the team.  Some questions are about both the site [MSE] and the engine [MSO, historically].

Comment: I can confirm that @Jeff is constantly active over at least the top proposals, which makes me believe that the whole team will be keeping an eye out!