# Common features for Stack Exchanges

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange-2.0

Should there be some sort of standardised list of features for new Stack Exchanges? What I'm thinking about is that different Stack Exchanges can make more or less use of 'custom' features.

For example, on of the most useful features for stats.stackexchange.com would be the ability to cross post between sites such as mathoverflow.com and stackexchange.com because there will be a lot of 'borderline' questions that may be more suited to another site. What might be less useful for stats.stackexchange.com would be hosted posting of photographs.

However, for cooking.stackexchange.com, cross posting right now is not particularly useful because there are few grey areas between the other sites and cooking. However hosting of photos, and adding a recipe 'module' to the cooking site would be very useful.

Should there be some sort of system for voting on standardised features so that the community can see what features would be most useful to add to each stack exchange site . Eventually I can inagine that there may be too many additional 'modules' for sites that switching all of them on at once may create too much clutter and user confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In general these should be discussed on the per-site metas.

Whether the engine gets the feature or not will be determined by the "strength" of the SE 2.0 site in the network, as well as how many other SE 2.0 sites could benefit from that feature.

Also, see Robert's answer here:
[Where should we post feature requests for Stack Exchange betas?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58397/where-should-we-post-feature-requests-for-stack-exchange-betas/58449#58449)

> If there's an idea/feature-request for a specific community, it's up to that community to vet the idea in the same way we do here (i.e. in their own meta). If the idea passes muster, it would be passed on to us for consideration, through their own governance.
>
> Of course, if the idea involves the core engine or the Network, the idea should be raised in http://meta.stackoverflow.com. Pretty cool, huh?